# jQuery clone a <div> to a dynamically created <div>

Tags: jquery

I want to clone the html of 'divhtml' to 'divPlainHtml' but the code below doesn't work: after its execution, $('#divPlainHtml') returns empty object []

```
$('#divhtml').clone(false).
      appendTo('<div id="divPlainHtml" style="display: none;"></div>')
```

Comment: If `#divPlainHtml` doesn't exist in the DOM, how can you append to it? I'm not sure what side-effects cloning elements with unique `id`s has, but it might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, `divPlainHtml` does not exist in the DOM to append to. Try this.

```
$('<div id="divPlainHtml" style="display: none;"></div>')
.appendTo(document.body)//Or specify the container where you want to append it
.append($('#divhtml').clone(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because divPlainHtml isn't on your page yet.

Append divPlainHtml to your page.

```
$('whereever').append("<div id='divPlainHtml'></div>");
```

Then do `$("#divPlainHtml").append($("divHtml").clone(false));`

Answer (score 1):

This is because is not in the DOM.

```
.appendTo('<div id="divPlainHtml" style="display: none;"></div>')
```

This appends your new element to a div that's not in the DOM, so `$('#divPlainHtml')` doesn't find it.

Instead of using `appendTo`, use `append`.

```
$('<div id="divPlainHtml" style="display: none;"></div>')
  .append($('#divhtml').clone(false));
```

You can add `divPlainHtml` to the DOM where you want.  Like this:

```
$('<div id="divPlainHtml" style="display: none;"></div>')
  .append($('#divhtml').clone(false)).appendTo('body');
```

NOTE: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID, so you should change `divhtml`'s ID after cloning it.

```
$('<div id="divPlainHtml" style="display: none;"></div>')
  .append($('#divhtml').clone(false).attr('id', 'divhtml2'));
```